# Can i create a dataframe from another dataframes rows

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Can I create a dataframe from below's rows , as columns of the new dataframe using Pyspark?

```
+------------+
|         col|
+------------|
|created_meta|
|  updated_at|
|updated_meta|
|        meta|
|        Year|
|  First Name|
|      County|
|         Sex|
|       Count|
+------------
```

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 2):

Two ways.

1. Using pivot:

```
df1 = df.groupBy().pivot('col').agg(F.lit(None)).limit(0)

df1.show()
+-----+------+---------+---+----+------------+----+----------+------------+
|Count|County|FirstName|Sex|Year|created_meta|meta|updated_at|updated_meta|
+-----+------+---------+---+----+------------+----+----------+------------+
+-----+------+---------+---+----+------------+----+----------+------------+
```

2. Creating it from scratch:

```
df2 = df.select([F.lit(r[0]) for r in df.collect()]).limit(0)

df2.show()
+------------+----------+------------+----+----+---------+------+---+-----+
|created_meta|updated_at|updated_meta|meta|Year|FirstName|County|Sex|Count|
+------------+----------+------------+----+----+---------+------+---+-----+
+------------+----------+------------+----+----+---------+------+---+-----+
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  // sorry in Scala + Spark
  import spark.implicits._

  import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

  val lst  = List("created_meta",
  "updated_at",
  "updated_meta",
  "meta",
  "Year",
  "First Name",
   "County",
  "Sex",
  "Count")


  val source = lst.toDF("col")

  source.show(false)
  //  +------------+
  //  |col         |
  //  +------------+
  //  |created_meta|
  //  |updated_at  |
  //  |updated_meta|
  //  |meta        |
  //  |Year        |
  //  |First Name  |
  //  |County      |
  //  |Sex         |
  //  |Count       |
  //  +------------+

  val l = source.select('col).as[String].collect.toList

  val df1 = l.foldLeft(source)((acc, col) => {
    acc.withColumn(col, lit(""))
  })

 val df2 = df1.drop("col")
 df2.printSchema()
 //  root
 //  |-- created_meta: string (nullable = false)
 //  |-- updated_at: string (nullable = false)
 //  |-- updated_meta: string (nullable = false)
 //  |-- meta: string (nullable = false)
 //  |-- Year: string (nullable = false)
 //  |-- First Name: string (nullable = false)
 //  |-- County: string (nullable = false)
 //  |-- Sex: string (nullable = false)
 //  |-- Count: string (nullable = false)


 df2.show(1, false)

 //  +------------+----------+------------+----+----+----------+------+---+-----+
 //  |created_meta|updated_at|updated_meta|meta|Year|First Name|County|Sex|Count|
 //  +------------+----------+------------+----+----+----------+------+---+-----+
 //  |            |          |            |    |    |          |      |   |     |
 //  +------------+----------+------------+----+----+----------+------+---+-----+
```